# Python 3 - A Specific Operation on a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of length n having positive numbers like:

```
list = [a,b,c,d,g,h,w,x,y,z]
```

where a,b,c... are all numbers. I want to check if the list has any any two consecutive pairs of numbers which satisfy the below criteria:

```
[w,x] and [y,z] such that w = z +/- 1 and x = y +/- 1 and abs(w-x) == abs(y-z)
```

for example -

```
>>> l
[0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6]
(2,5) and (4,1) are such consecutive pairs of list elements.
```

Any tips will be useful.

Comment: You don't need tips, you need an algorithm for this. :)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think you have an error in either the problem statement or the example, since `2 - 5 != 4 - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `zip` function :

```
>>> z=list(zip(l[0::2],l[1::2]))
>>> new=zip(z,z[1:])
>>> [([w,x],[y,z]) for [w,x],[y,z] in new if abs(w-z)==1 and abs(x-y)== 1 and abs(w-x) == abs(y-z)]
[([2, 5], [4, 1])]
```

*Note* that for long lists you can use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`.

Another example :

```
>>> l=[0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1]
>>> z=zip(l[0::2],l[1::2])
>>> new=zip(z,z[1:])
>>> [([w,x],[y,z]) for [w,x],[y,z] in new if abs(w-z)==1 and abs(x-y)== 1 and abs(w-x) == abs(y-z)]
[([2, 5], [4, 1])]
```

Based on comments notes for another cases as a more complete way you can do :

```
>>> l=[8, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6]
>>> z1=zip(l[0::2],l[1::2])
>>> new1=zip(z1,z1[1:])

>>> z2=zip(l[1::2],l[2::2])
>>> new2=zip(z2,z2[1:])

>>> total=new1+new2
>>> [([w,x],[y,z]) for [w,x],[y,z] in total if abs(w-z)==1 and abs(x-y)== 1 and abs(w-x) == abs(y-z)]
[([2, 5], [4, 1])]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if one of the pairs goes odd-index, even-index instead of even-index, odd-index.

Comment: This gives me the error : TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @FallenAngel I missed that you are in python 3 you need to convert the z to list.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah it could has any shapes also it could be done with `izip`.but i just write for this case

Comment: @Kasra, I'm not sure if you got what user2357112 means. If you use `l[1:]` instead of `l`, your algorithm won't find the solution anymore!

Comment: You can make it work by replacing `zip(l[0::2], l[1::2])` with `zip(l, l[1:])` and replacing `zip(z, z[1:])` with `zip(z, z[2:])` ;)

Comment: @swenzel Yeah, i update the question with that case!